# Open VideoStream using OpenCV 4.5.1 works on Windows but fails on Docker python:3.9.2-slim-buster for specific IP cam

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ffmpeg

I have 2 ip cameras - one of Hikvision and another of Provision ISR. Both use Onvif and work on VLC.
I've written a simple python script to record images every 5 sec from their video stream.
On Windows 10, using VSCode they both work as expected. Once deployed to a Docker container, my script works as expected with the Hikvision but fails with the Provision ISR - it doesn't open the stream.

Running `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())"` on windows (venv 3.9.2) and on docker machine bring slightly different results but it's beyond my understanding to take something out of it...
Here is the Windows one:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
  Version control:               4.5.1

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-01-02T14:30:58Z
    Host:                        Windows 6.3.9600 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.18.4
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.24241.7)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 
/MP  /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 
/MP  /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP   /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /INCREMENTAL:NO  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmtd.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /NODEFAULTLIB:atlthunk.lib /debug /INCREMENTAL  /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:libcpmt.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          ade wsock32 comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.6-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-wvn_it83/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.9/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-wvn_it83/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.9/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
    Include path:                C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-wvn_it83/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python39-x64/python.exe (ver 3.9)
    Libraries:                   C:/Python39-x64/libs/python39.lib (ver 3.9.0)
    numpy:                       C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-build-env-sk7r7w_5/overlay/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.3)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            C:/Python27-x64/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    C:/Users/appveyor/AppData/Local/Temp/1/pip-req-build-wvn_it83/_skbuild/win-amd64-3.9/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is the Docker one (python:3.9.2-slim-buster):

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
  Version control:               4.5.1-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-01-02T13:04:10Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-1077-gcp x86_64
    CMake:                       3.18.4
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/c++  (ver 9.3.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          ade Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent /lib64/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.15.0)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.6-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.5.13)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.109.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.61.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.60.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.8.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /tmp/pip-req-build-ddpkm6fn/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /tmp/pip-req-build-ddpkm6fn/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /tmp/pip-req-build-ddpkm6fn/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp39-cp39/bin/python (ver 3.9)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.9.a (ver 3.9.0)
    numpy:                       /tmp/pip-build-env-jqrfyj0w/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.19.3)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            /bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /tmp/pip-req-build-ddpkm6fn/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

If relevant, the docker is installed on an Intel NUC with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04

If relevant, this is the dockerfile I've used to build the image:

```
FROM python:3.9.2-slim-buster as builder

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
# Without this setting, Python never prints anything out.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./Cam/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y

WORKDIR /app

FROM builder
COPY ./Cam .
CMD ["python", "camStreamer.py"]
```

and last, this is the script code (simplified):

```
import os, logging, threading
from os.path import join
import sys, inspect, datetime, time
from pathlib import Path
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils.video import VideoStream

def StartRecording(showVideoWindow, interval, imagePath):
    key = None
    cam = VideoStream(os.getenv("CAM_RTSP")).start()
    counter = 0
    try:
        while True:
            ## 2 min retry to connect if frame is None
            if counter > 60/interval*2: break

            ts = time.time()
            ## Wait for [interval] seconds
            while ts + interval > time.time():
                continue
            print(f"Counter: {counter}, ts: {str(ts)}")

            frame = cam.read()
            if frame is None:
                counter += 1
                continue
            counter = 0

            print("frame is valid")
            if showVideoWindow:
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=1200)
                cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)

            imageName = f"{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S')}.jpg"
            cv2.imwrite(join(imagePath, imageName), frame)
            print("saved image to disk")

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord('q') or key == ord('r'):
                break

    except Exception as e:
        exc_tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        extra = ""
        print(f"{inspect.stack()[0][3]}: {e} (lineno: {exc_tb.tb_lineno}) {extra}")
    finally:
        if showVideoWindow: cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cam.stop()
        return key


while True:
    log.warning(f"Starting {Name}")
    key = StartRecording(
                showVideoWindow=(Env.startswith("development") and os.getenv("SHOW_VIDEO") == "True"),
                interval=int(os.getenv("SAVE_IMAGE_INTERVAL")),
                imagePath=os.getenv('CAPTURE_FOLDER')
                )
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

I apologize for the very long post. Hopefully someone can put me on the right direction...

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you reach *Provision ISR* from docker.

Comment: Yes, both cameras are on the same lan. But thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem on Linux using a compiled version o ffmpeg and opencv.

Follow this link to compile FFMPEG first

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

To compile OpenCV on Ubuntu 20

```
apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y sudo openjdk-8-jdk python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-numpy  axel \
    tesseract-ocr libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr-eng tesseract-ocr-por ant \ 
    dcfldd curl ca-certificates  apt-utils python3-testresources \
    build-essential cmake git pkg-config libgtk-3-dev \
    libavcodec-dev  libavformat-dev libswscale-dev  \
    libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev \
    openexr libatlas-base-dev   libtbb2 libtbb-dev  libopenexr-dev  \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev  autoconf automake git-core \
    libass-dev libfreetype6-dev  libsdl2-dev  libtool libva-dev \
    libvdpau-dev libxcb1-dev  libxcb-shm0-dev \
    libxcb-xfixes0-dev  texinfo wget zlib1g-dev nasm \
    yasm  libx265-dev libnuma-dev libvpx-dev libavresample-dev \
    libfdk-aac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopus-dev   \
    libjpeg8-dev libtiff5-dev   libv4l-dev  dialog libopenblas-dev  \ 
    liblapack-dev libblas-dev ffmpeg locales apt-utils \
    unzip yasm checkinstall libavresample-dev \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    x264  libfaac-dev libtheora-dev \
    libfaac-dev  libvorbis-dev \
    libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev \
    libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libxine2-dev  v4l-utils \
    libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler curl\
    libgoogle-glog-dev libgflags-dev gfortran \
    libgphoto2-dev libeigen3-dev libhdf5-dev
```

Download OpenCV

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git 
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git 

cd opencv && mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opencv_contrib/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
        -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
        -D WITH_TBB=ON \
        -D WITH_V4L=ON \
        -D WITH_QT=OFF \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
        -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 ..

cd /opencv/build && make -j$(nproc) && make install && cd / && rm -rvf ./opencv && rm -rfv ./opencv_contrib
```

Comment: Hi, your answer might be more helpful if you could add more details on how to use compiled versions of ffmpeg and opencv in case that's not clear to the OP!